# Why does a relative measurement offset the starting position of an element?

Tags: gsap

This fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/NK3pe/69/, has a relative position of `-=10px`, meaning the timeLine will cause the element to travel `-10px` from its starting position, which is set via css.

```
trackMaster.from( $('.particle')[i], randomNumber(10,100), { top:'-=10px', ease: Linear.easeNone, repeat: -1 }, 0 );
```

This fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/NK3pe/70/, has a relative position of `-=20px`, meaning the timeLine will cause the element to travel`-20px`.

However, notice the dots' starting position are are higher up the air.

And with http://jsfiddle.net/NK3pe/71/, `-=30px` the dots are even highter in the air!

**I need the dots to stay at the same starting position regardless of how far the element has to travel!** (Obviously, I would have thought -.-)

```
var trackMaster = new TimelineLite({ paused: false, repeat: -1 });

function randomNumber(minimum, maximum){
    return Math.round (Math.random() * (maximum - minimum) + minimum )
}

function randomHue(){
    switch(randomNumber(0,4)){
        case(0):
            return 'B';
            break;
        case(1):
            return 'C';
            break;
        case(2):
            return 'D';
            break;        
        case(3):
            return 'E';
            break;
        case(4):
            return 'F';
            break;
    }
}



function addParticle(particleClass){
    var size = randomNumber(20, 30),
        hue = randomHue(),
        shade = randomNumber(0,9)
    // hue + shade + hue + shade + hue + shade +

    $('#display').append("<span class='" + particleClass + "' style='left: 0px; font-size: " + size + "px; color: white" + " '> . </span>"); 
}

for(i = 0; i < 30; i++){
   addParticle('particle');

   trackMaster.from( $('.particle')[i], randomNumber(10,100), { top:'-=30px', ease: Linear.easeNone, repeat: -1 }, 0 );

}

//trackMaster.time(6);

function midAnimation(){
     trackMaster.time(2);   
}

$('#initial_state').on('click', function(){
    trackMaster.time(8);
});

$('#restart').on('click', function(){
    trackMaster.restart();
});

$('#pause').on('click', function(){
    trackMaster.pause();
});

$('#resume').on('click', function(){
    trackMaster.resume();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the intended behavior of GSAP's `from` function of their TimeLine.

**What it's doing:**

The demo, instead of starting at 0 and going to up (since in the window's coordinate system `(0,0)` is the top left of the screen) to `n`, the value you specified like `10px` etc., it is instead going *from* that value of `n` (`-=10px`) *to* 0 since that's the position you specified.

**How to fix it:**

You can either specify the original position, meaning setting `n` (`-10px`) as the `top` position in CSS, and then go *from* 0 in your TimeLine

*or*

You can us the `to` function instead:

```
trackMaster.to( 
    $('.particle')[i], 
    randomNumber(10,100), 
    { top:'+=30px', ease: Linear.easeNone, repeat: -1 }, 
    0 
);
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/NK3pe/138/) of using the `to` function